# JasperReports 5.6: Could not load the following font

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

I am facing the problem, that *JasperReports* still cannot find the Arial font.

I created a simple Maven Project with following structure and included it to my main application. So the main application contains the installed JAR in classpath:

```
- jasperreports_extension.properties
- fonts
  |-> arial
    |-> ariali.ttf
    |-> arialbi.ttf
    |-> arialbd.ttf
    |-> arial.ttf
  |-> fonts.xml
```

But I still see following Exception while exporting report to PDF.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : Arial
pdfEncoding   : Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : true
```

**jasperreports_extension.properties**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.arial=fonts/fonts.xml
```

**fonts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Arial">
        <normal>fonts/arial/arial.ttf</normal>
        <bold>fonts/arial/arialbd.ttf</bold>
        <italic>fonts/arial/ariali.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>fonts/arial/arialbi.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

**Template**

```
<font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

Comment: What version to jasper report are you using?

Comment: JasperReport and iReport version: 5.6.0

Comment: I also had your same problem with the 5.5.0, and I solved it   by switching to 5.0.0

Comment: Thank you, but I still see the Exception, even with 5.0.0

Comment: I still have this problem, and still cannot find a solution until now. May I can provide you more resources?

Comment: Try to add the fonts within your jdk folder (jdk1.x.x_xx/jre/lib/fonts). This will make you lose portability  but at least we can understand if the problem is the packaging o other

Comment: Im facing the same issue , could you please tell me how did u resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You must give the correct name of font for the PDF exporter. Your fonts are presents into the embedded fonts jar. You don't need to put them again into the classes directory ;-)

There is the correct fonts.xml content for pdf exporter (perhaps the names are case sensitive, be careful) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
<fontFamily name="Arial">
    <normal>
      <ttf>fonts/Arial/ARIAL.TTF</ttf>
      <pdf>fonts/Arial/ARIAL.TTF</pdf>
    </normal>
    <bold>
      <ttf>fonts/Arial/ARIALBD.TTF</ttf>
      <pdf>fonts/Arial/ARIALBD.TTF</pdf>
    </bold>
    <italic>
      <ttf>fonts/Arial/ARIALI.TTF</ttf>
      <pdf>fonts/Arial/ARIALI.TTF</pdf>
    </italic>
    <boldItalic>
      <ttf>fonts/Arial/ARIALBI.TTF</ttf>
      <pdf>fonts/Arial/ARIALBI.TTF</pdf>
    </boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding>Cp1252</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    <exportFonts>
    </exportFonts>
</fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

I hope this help.

Regards,
T.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the template itself: At one font-tag the `<fontName>` property was missing:

Does not work:

```
<font size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Arial"/>
```

Does work:

```
<font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

Comment: I don't get. I have the same problem but only on Linux. On Windows it works fine, so, I don't think the problem is the template, but the loading of the extension.

Comment: @Gustavo oddly enough, it's happening to me on Windows, not on Linux. Running out of things to try...

Answer (score 1):

Copy the fonts files **(*.ttf)** into the folder:

```
/path/to/app/WEB-INF/classes/***HERE***
```

You app will get the fonts from here :)

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.. I added the ttf file in the same place as u suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**Another Solution** Worked For Me is:

JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name", "Helvetica");
                    JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding", "UTF-8");
                    JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded", "true");

If you set parameters from java side, 
you have to specify font.name and **Helvetica** saves the day. 
I tried Arial here but threw the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using:

```
<font fontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

I had to remove `pdffontName`, the correct font tag is:

```
<font fontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1256"/>
```

**Note**
I am using a font jar that contains the following .xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>

   <fontFamily name="Arial">
       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/arial.ttf]]></normal>
       <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>


</fontFamilies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I read it somewhere and it worked for me, You should write full path instead of relative path.